# How to remove a specific symbol from stage when clicking on it in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have added a few instances of a movieclip (a simple image of an apple) on to the stage at random x and y. Now I am trying to click on each one to remove them.

Here is what I have:

```
public function Apples() {

        for(var count:int=1; count<=10; count++){
            var apple = new Apple();
            apple.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            apple.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;    
            apple.name = count;
            stage.addChild(apple);
            }

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);



        function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
            stage.removeChild(e.target);
            }
}
```

I get the following error if I try to compile:

```
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated  type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

I have also tried substituting e.target.name for e.target. In this case the program runs, but as soon as I click on the apple, I get the following error in the output log:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "9" to flash.display.DisplayObject.
at MethodInfo-4()
```

So is there any way to remove the specific object that I am clicking on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onClick event handler try something like:

```
var displayObject:DisplayObject = (DisplayObject) (e.target);
displayObject.parent.removeChild(displayObject);
```

You may also want to make sure the event handler is added to the display object using a weak reference, if it is meant to be completely gone/removed on click.

Comment: IMO weak listeners are a double edged sword for beginners. They make things easier, which isn't always a good thing when you are learning how things work.